# Can't show text from an input when click button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to code a simple form that will get some text and then display in a dialog box when i click on the submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Página Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div>
        <h1>Questão 4</h1>
    </div>
</header>

<div>
    <label for="texto">Texto: </label>
    <textarea name="texto" id="texto" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" id="submit">Enviar</button>
</div>  
<script>

    var teste = $("texto").val;

    $("submit").on("click", function(){
        $("teste").dialog("open");
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on the button nothing happens, and i've tried some ways of doing this script and none seem to work.

Comment: missing `#` should be....`$("#teste").dialog("open");` and `$("#texto").val()`

Comment: Thanks, that was really my mistake, but it's still not working here. I open the .html page, type something, click the button and nothing happens.

Comment: Missing `#`  ....`$("#submit").on("click", function(){`

Comment: **1)** From what I see above, there is no element with an id `teste` which could act as a dialog. **2)** `.dialog()` is a jQuery-UI method and the library is not loaded. **3)** Open the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)... You certainly have meaningful errors there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some `#` and `.val` is a function so use `.val()`.

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do with the dialog box, but should try something like this:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    var teste = $('#texto').val();

    alert(teste);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var teste = $("texto").val;
    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        console.log("something happens");
    });})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using document ready. Also if you want you can have separate javascript file and do much more operations

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Página Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div>
        <h1>Questão 4</h1>
    </div>
</header>

<div>
    <label for="texto">Texto: </label>
    <textarea name="texto" id="texto" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" id="submit">Enviar</button>
</div>  
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
   var teste = $('#texto').val();
    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        alert("teste")
    });})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The document ready wrapper is a nice advise... But in no way is the issue here since the script is below the HTML markup. -- A separate .js file does not allow *much more operations* at all, it only allow a script to be used in multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$("teste").dialog("open");` or `$("texto").val()` jQuery will look for an element `<teste></teste>` in the dom. Since the element doesn't exist in your example, it won't do anything.

Perhaps you're missing a `.` or `#` in the selector you're passing to `$(selector)`?